# Let $f(x),g(x)$ be positive strictly increasing function. When can I assure that $h(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f(x),g(x)$ be positive strictly increasing function.
>   When can I assure that $h(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is increasing or decreasing?

I'm trying to prove that a function is increasing, but is too complicated so i'm looking for some criteria that would help.

I tried the derivative, but that does not work because the function I'm dealing with are too complicated to derive, so I'm asking for the case when the functions are nondifferentiable, thanks.

Comment: No, in general that is not true (one of the functions  can increase very rapidly at the beginning and then  "stop his growth" to an horizontal asymptote,for example)

Comment: yes, I Know, but I wondering if there is a condition for the functions that can ensure increasing.

Comment: @GuadalupeAnimation What do you mean with "not differentiable"? That there exists no derivative, or just that it is too hard to compute?

Comment: When the derivative does not exists.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, on $(0,\infty)$; both are increasing, but the quotient $f(x)/g(x)=1/x$ is decreasing. On the other hand $g(x)/f(x)=x$, which is increasing. It is possible to give examples when the quotient is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find how is the behavior of h(x) we have to calculate it's derivative so:

$$h' = \frac{f'g-g'f}{g^2}$$

in order that this fraction be positive(so h be increasing) we must have:

$$f'g-g'f\ge0  \;\;\;\;\; \; \Rightarrow \frac{f'}{f} \ge \frac{g'}{g}$$
now integrating yields:
$$ln(f)\ge ln(g) + constant \Rightarrow f \ge constant \times g $$

so you must identify that f is always greater than g and since g and f are both positive this test can be done easily. on the other hand if 
$$g \ge constant \times f $$
then h is decreasing.

this just popped into my head now but there must be more sophisticated ways.

***************************edit***********************

After discussion with S.harp he proved to me the above statement is wrong and the counter example is the one in the comments below. so I edit this answer this way:
that constant is an arbitrary positive number. so for above solution to be true there must be an interval of the form $(\beta,+ \infty) \; $ in which the inequality $$f \ge constant \times g $$ or the other one holds for any positive arbitrary constant . this happens when the growth rate of f is greater than g other whise the claim could be wrong. for example: $f= 100+x  \;  and \; g = x$ although $f>g$ but $h = f/g $ is decreasing.  so if growth rate of f is greater than g then the claim is right.

I apologize for wrong response.
also thanks to S.harp for revealing that first claim was wrong.

Comment: $f,g$ are not differentiable.

Comment: actually it is useful, because the functions that i'm using are differentiable, but I can't derive because it makes the function even larger and complicated, and maybe the condition $f\geq c g$ would work even if the functions are nondifferentiable.

Comment: But maybe the conversely is not true.

Comment: ummmm  I thought derivative of f and g cant be calculated because of complexity. if they are not differentiable then my answer is wrong sorry. but if they are differentiable the idea is simple. cause both f and g are positive and increasing then if one of them grows faster then behavior of h can be predicted.

Comment: It is not enough for $f>g$ to hold, take for example $f$ thats starts constant at for example 10, then after a while goes up to $11$, whereas $g$ starts at $1$ increasing linearly to $2$ and then stays constant. At the beginning $f/g$ is decreasing.

Comment: s.harp at this case f and g are not differentiable see when changing from constant to linear and vice versa  function is continuous but not differentiable cause derivative is from right and left are not equal

Comment: Then make them differentiable by rounding out the corners, it doesn't matter. Alternatively take $f=100$ just the constant funtion on $(1,2)$ and $g=id$ the identity on this set. Both are differentiable and $f/g$ is decreasing.

Comment: the inequality must hold for infinite interval for example (a,+infinity) because f and g are always increasing from the specification in problem. and then the behavior of h can be determined in the interval (a,+infinity).

Comment: Take $g= id$ on $(0,\infty)$, $f(x)=100 + \chi_{(2,\infty)} (x) \exp(-\frac{1}{(x-2)^2}) x$ where $\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases}1 &x \in A\\0 & x \notin A\end{cases}$. The condition is fulfilled and the statement is false.

Comment: in this case f(x) is decreasing dude   :|  besides  g > f for (101,+infinity)

Comment: still g>f for (101,+infinity)

Comment: $f$ is increasing.. since $\exp(-1/x^2)$ is an increasing function for $x>0$. And look closer athe the function, the exponential has been multiplied with $x$, since $\exp(-1/x^2)$ asymptotically approaches one extremely quickly, it is intuitively clear that $f>g$ holds always. Showing it is some analysis but not difficult.

Comment: g is identity , right? so for x>101 we have g>101 but max(f) is 100 for so called interval. so g>f

Comment: No... that is not true.... Why don't you just look at the function, maybe draw it... $f$ is asymptotically $100 +x$

Comment: nice proposal i plot them all. h is decreasing and contradicts with the f>g. but i went back to calculating derivative but the function is not differentiable. because of chi function introduced. also x=2 is a singular point and we know at the sides of singularity conditions on increasing and decreasing wont hold like hyperbolic function s(x) = 1/x.

Comment: Note that $\exp(-1/(x-2)^2)$ has derivative zero at $x=2$, so this is indeed a smooth function. You could also just remove the $\chi$ and replace $\exp(-1/(x-2)^2)$ with $\exp(-1/x^2)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35754/discussion-between-s-harp-and-k-k-mcdonald).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The derivative of a function indicates when does a function increase/decrease and how much

Comment: The proble is that I cant derive, because the functions are too long

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about general real functions without any extra structure, I  don't think you're going to get so satisfying of an answer, since those can be quite pathological. If f and g are highly discontinuous then the value of f/g near x in general gives little information about the value at x. If you wanted to impose some restrictions on growth rates or somehow bound f and g between nicely behaved functions there would be more to say. Also, maybe you might want to simplify to the case where f and g are sequences rather than real functions, in case your question proves too difficult.